# Why don't my if statements check the values of my function correctly?

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I have code elsewhere that puts a pointer in a position based on the `AttackInfo.Target` value. I also have code that determines whether my characters are dead, using the `Stats[lifeStatus]` array reference, where 0 is dead and 1 is alive.

I want the `Target` to skip over the values of dead characters so you can only select living characters to attack. However, it seems to have no effect.

Why does it not work?

```
else if (state == CHARACTER1TARGETCHOICE) {
    attackButton.enabled = false;
    abilitiesButton.enabled = false;
    itemButton.enabled = false;
    defendButton.enabled = false;
    fleeButton.enabled = false;
    if (pointer.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().enabled == false) {
        pointer.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().enabled = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        character1AttackInfo.Target -= 1;
        bool checkTargetAlive = false;
        while (checkTargetAlive) {
            if (enemy1Stats [lifeStatus] == 0 && character1AttackInfo.Target == 1) {
                character1AttackInfo.Target -= 1;
            } else if (enemy2Stats [lifeStatus] == 0 && character1AttackInfo.Target == 2) {
                character1AttackInfo.Target -= 1;
            } else if (enemy3Stats [lifeStatus] == 0 && character1AttackInfo.Target == 3) {
                character1AttackInfo.Target -= 1;
            } else if (enemy4Stats [lifeStatus] == 0 && character1AttackInfo.Target == 4) {
                character1AttackInfo.Target -= 1;
            } else if (character1AttackInfo.Target == 0) {
                character1AttackInfo.Target = 4;
            } else {
                checkTargetAlive = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

In this part of the script, the lower the enemy's number, the higher they are on the screen. Therefore, when the up arrow is pressed, the target's number goes down so the cursor will move up. The cursor moving to the different places above the characters already works perfectly. The target just wont skip for some reason. Once an enemy dies and so enemy1Stats == 0 is true and the Target is 1 also, it still doesn't skip.

Comment: Does this `enemy1Stats [lifeStatus] == 0` equal `true` and does this  `character1AttackInfo.Target == 1` equal `true`? Have you checked.

Comment: It depends. The enemy1Stats [lifeStatus] == 0 is only true if the enemy is dead, which is all part of a greater script, and the character1AttackInfo.Target == 1 is only true if the cursor has been moved there, which is the purpose of this script. In this instance, assume enemy1Stats [lifeStatus] == 0 is true, and that character1AttackInfo.Target should be true for a moment, but then should change. But it doesn't change. Thats the problem.

Comment: You have `bool checkTargetAlive = false;` followed by `while (checkTargetAlive)`. How is that supposed to run?

Comment: You're right..... Im stupid thank you

Comment: Guess I should have posted that as an answer instead...

Comment: You still should @c.helling

Answer (score 1):

That block of code isn't called:

```
bool checkTargetAlive = false;
```

followed by

```
while (checkTargetAlive)
```

As a general comment, I don't quite understand how your game logic is supposed to work, but that block in the question has some definite code smell. That can't possibly be the cleanest way to implement your game logic.

Comment: I agree, and once you have that many if else and that many values to check there will be a better way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

So I just accidentally set checkTargetAlive to false ahead of time. That made it so the while loop never ran, which made the cursor not work correctly. Just setting it to true ahead of time made it work like a charm:

```
else if (state == CHARACTER1TARGETCHOICE) {
    attackButton.enabled = false;
    abilitiesButton.enabled = false;
    itemButton.enabled = false;
    defendButton.enabled = false;
    fleeButton.enabled = false;
    if (pointer.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().enabled == false) {
        pointer.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().enabled = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
        character1AttackInfo.Target -= 1;
        bool checkTargetAlive = true;
        while (checkTargetAlive) {
            if (enemy1Stats [lifeStatus] == 0 && character1AttackInfo.Target == 1) {
                character1AttackInfo.Target -= 1;
            } else if (enemy2Stats [lifeStatus] == 0 && character1AttackInfo.Target == 2) {
                character1AttackInfo.Target -= 1;
            } else if (enemy3Stats [lifeStatus] == 0 && character1AttackInfo.Target == 3) {
                character1AttackInfo.Target -= 1;
            } else if (enemy4Stats [lifeStatus] == 0 && character1AttackInfo.Target == 4) {
                character1AttackInfo.Target -= 1;
            } else if (character1AttackInfo.Target == 0) {
                character1AttackInfo.Target = 4;
            } else {
                checkTargetAlive = false;
            }
        }
    }
```